# Is there any method using python libraries without installing?

Tags: python, web-scraping

Since company's computer require admin right / presmission when installing anythings, is there any method using extend python libraries without installing (e.g. selenium, requests, beautifulsoup4, PyPDF2 and OpenPyXL).

Comment: `--user` shouldn't require any privileges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Go to [PyPI](https://pypi.org)
- find your package,
- go to the `Home` at the left sidebar (most of them redirected to `GitHub` or `GitLab`)
- then download the repository and install the package locally, something like this:

`pip install /home/yourname/requests`

> pip install directory_of_setup.py

or use the package without installing it, `import` the source code to your project